# Unable to SSH From External

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, centos-7, selinux

I have a CentOS 7.5 machine behind a TP Link router.

I have enabled the port forwarding in the router (and rebooted).

However, for some reason, I can ping the router but I can't telnet nor ssh to that machine through port 22.

```
$ telnet [public IP] 22
Trying [public IP]...
telnet: connect to address [public IP]: Connection refused

$ ssh root@[public IP]
ssh: connect to host [public IP] port 22: Connection refused
```

I also tried another user but same thing.

I did stop firewall.d:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl stop firewalld
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2018-05-22 10:20:42 CST; 4min 26s ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
  Process: 733 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid $FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 733 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 21 00:49:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
May 21 00:49:14 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
May 22 10:20:41 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
May 22 10:20:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
```

And I did temporarily disable SELinux:

```
[root@localhost ~]# setenforce 0
[root@localhost ~]# sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      31
```

sshd is indeed running:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-05-22 10:42:03 CST; 8min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 11861 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─11861 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

May 22 10:42:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
May 22 10:42:03 localhost.localdomain sshd[11861]: Server listening on :: port 22.
May 22 10:42:03 localhost.localdomain sshd[11861]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
May 22 10:42:03 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

Any idea?

Comment: Just for testing - can you ssh to it (not from external, but from other machine within your internal network?)

Comment: Also have you tried port forwarding a different external port number on the public IP? There have been cases where your ISP will be blocking port 22 by default. So try a high number external port (eg. 52222) and port forward to 22 (into your internal network) and see if that works out.

Comment: @Darius atm, I don't have another machine to test.  But I just did test to ssh [private IP of the machine], and it worked.  So it means sshd is working properly.  I just changed the external port to something like 50K+, and rebooted but still the same thing.

Comment: So sshd works. Means your port forwarding not set up correctly then?

Comment: That's how I feel.  But port forwarding setup on TP Link is quite straightforward.

Comment: Have you successfully port forwarded anything else on this router? It sounds like you are using your own custom equipment behind the ISP modem. Are you sure the TP Link has a public IP? You might be double NATing.

Comment: @Appleoddity good catch.  I just noticed that the router doesn't have a public IP.  I will figure out the detail when the admin is in.  Thanks!